# SQLite windows universal application

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a windows universal application for the phone, desktop, tablet and wanted to know the best way to add SQLite to the project. I would prefer not to create two libraries one for the phone and one for the tablet desktop if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to go in your visual studio 2013 and select tools, extensions and updates and find the SQLite. Then install "SQLite for windows phone 8.1" and "SQLite for windows runtime (Windows 8.1)". 
Later select your phone project and download sqlite-net nuguet package and add two references in your phone project the first is "SQLite for windows phone 8.1" and the second is "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package for Windows Phone" do the same for runtime project, finally (but it's optional) u can move de auxiliar classes SQLite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs in your "shared project" and u can delete this classes from windows phone project and windows runtime project.

U can follow this old tutorial too:

http://blog.tpcware.com/2014/04/universal-app-with-sqlite-part-1/

http://blog.tpcware.com/2014/05/universal-app-with-sqlite-part-2/

If you have a questions just ask, but for the next time find a little more in StackOverflow this question was answered a lot of times.

Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

From my experiences that I had transformed my company from a traditional local server to the Cloud.
Criteria to consider.
First, you can try to use Azure Mobile Services.
Second, consider the backup of your data.
Third, consider the bandwidth.